# First order formula describing connected components

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory, o-minimal

I ask this question here after no answer came up in [the original MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528675/first-order-description-of-connected-components?noredirect=1#comment9521770_4528675).

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1,P\}$ where $P$ is some $n$-ary relation symbol. Is there a formula $\psi(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{L}$, such that for every expansion $\mathcal{S}$ of the real field such that $P$ is interpreted as a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\psi(x,y)$ is evaluated to $1$ if $x,y$ are in the same connected component of $X$, and $0$ otherwise?

For example, the formula $\forall\epsilon\exists y P(y)\wedge|x-y|<\epsilon$ defines the closure of $X$, and my point is that it works for all $X$. Can we do the same for connected components?

I am pretty sure that the answer is no, but I don’t know how to prove it. What if we restrict to o-minimal expansions of $\mathbb{R}$? While by cellular decomposition we know that that connected components are uniformly definable, I still think they are not “universally” definable as in my question.

Any ideas or references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nice question! Note that a negative answer (which I also expect) will need to use the niceness of the specific structure of the field of reals: if we (say) expand the reals by a predicate naming the integers, we can more-or-less quantify over open sets and so talk about connectedness directly.

Comment: You can write down formulas $\phi_t(x,y)$ expressing that $y$ is reachable from $x$ using $t$ line segments included in $X$. Then $\{X\text{ is open},\psi(x,y)\}\cup\{\neg\phi_t(x,y):t\in\mathbb N\}$ is inconsistent, but all its finite subsets are consistent (for $n\ge2$), contradicting compactness.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue: this argument shows that there is no formula $\psi$ that works for all real-closed fields, but it does not refute the existence of one that works for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I have a question about your comment. I don’t easily see that your theory is inconsistent. Perhaps you should add $Thm(\mathbb{R})$ to it. Even then, it is not clear for me. I think I would be convinced if in every model of $Thm(\mathbb{R})$ every continuous function on closed bounded sets attains its extrema. Is that true?

Comment: As I already mentioned, the comment does not work.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek My question is to understand why your comment shows no formula works for all real-closed fields…

Comment: @Espace'etale I suppose the second comment does not work either, the way I wrote it. It should have said something along the lines of “every finite subset is satisfiable in $\mathbb R$, but this only implies the whole set is satisfiable in a real-closed field extending $\mathbb R$, rather than in $\mathbb R$ itself”.

Comment: The standard (second-order) topological theory of connectedness works only for the field of real numbers, all other real fields are zero-dimensional, so the connected components are just singletons. Since from the first-order point of view the real line is indistinguishable from a real closed field, I hope that no formula can desribe the connectedness (in the standard topological sense). However there is a notion of semi-algebraic connectedness, which should work for all real closed fields.

Comment: The phrase “expansion of the real field” is ambiguous between expanding the language and expanding the field (eg using $\mathbb{R}(t)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$). For the first option, it might be clearer to replace “for every expansion” with “in every model of $\mathcal{L}$ with the standard interpretations of $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$”. Also, given the motivating example, it would make sense to include $<$ in the language explicitly.